# How to fix SonarLint Cognitive Complexity Error for multiple If-Else conditions

Tags: java, spring-boot, if-statement, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have to write a lot of conditions, but SonarLint is giving me error, asking to refactor the method to reduce its cognitive complexity.

How to resolve this. I tried `switch`-case, but that is also giving the same error.

```
public enum ExampleEnum {
    UNKNOWN(-1),
    D0_D100(0),
    D100_D200(100),
    D200_D300(200),
    D300_D400(300),
    D400_D500(400),
    D500_D600(500),
    D600_D700(600),
    D700_D800(700),
    D800_D900(800),
    D900_D1000(900);
    
    private int score;
    
    ExampleEnum(int score) {
        this.score = score;
    }
}

public static ExampleEnum getScoreType(Integer score) {
    if (Objects.isNull(score) || score < D0_D100.score) {
        return UNKNOWN;
    } else if (score >= D0_D100.score && score < D100_D200.score) {
        return D0_D100;
    } else if (score >= D100_D200.score && score < D200_D300.score) {
        return D100_D200;
    } else if (score >= D200_D300.score && score < D300_D400.score) {
        return D200_D300;
    } else if (score >= D300_D400.score && score < D400_D500.score) {
        return D300_D400;
    } else if (score >= D400_D500.score && score < D500_D600.score) {
        return D400_D500;
    } else if (score >= D500_D600.score && score < D600_D700.score) {
        return D500_D600;
    } else if (score >= D600_D700.score && score < D700_D800.score) {
        return D600_D700;
    } else if (score >= D700_D800.score && score < D800_D900.score) {
        return D700_D800;
    } else if (score >= D800_D900.score && score < D900_D1000.score) {
        return D800_D900;
    } else {
        return D900_D1000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions about optimizing running code is better asked at [codereview.SE]

Comment: It is not an error (or shouldn't be interpreted as such), it is just a heuristic that suggests that using a different solution might be better for understanding of the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the logic into a loop. something like:

```
public static ExampleEnum getScoreType(Integer score) {
    if (Objects.isNull(score) || score < D0_D100.score) {
        return UNKNOWN;
    for (int i =0; i< ExampleEnum.values().length-1;i++) {
        if (ExampleEnum.values()[i].score <= score && ExampleEnum.values()[i+1].score > score )
            return ExampleEnum.values()[i];
    }
    return D900_D1000;
}
```

Comment: It might even be possible to use the enum itself to apply the range check, which would - in my opinion - simplify that if condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can use of the Stream API to remove this redundancy.

For that, you make use of the fact that the *natural order* of your *enum-members* reflects the order of the corresponding `score`.

As the source of the stream, you can use an array returned by the `values()` call or an `EnumSet` (which a specialized ordered collection) generated via [`EnumSet.allOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/EnumSet.html#allOf(java.lang.Class)).

While iterating over the *enum-members* we need to find the first constant which `score` is equal or less to the given score. Because `score` property of your *enum* represent the lower boundary of the range, only one condition would be sufficient to find out if the *given score* falls into the range corresponding to a particular *enum-member*.

This logic can be expressed by using combination of operations `filter()` + `findFirst()`:

```
public static ExampleEnum getScoreType(Integer score) {
    if (score == null || score < ExampleEnum.D0_D100.score) {
        return ExampleEnum.UNKNOWN;
    }
    
    return EnumSet.allOf(ExampleEnum.class).stream()
        .filter(e -> score >= e.score)
        .findFirst()
        .orElse(ExampleEnum.D900_D1000);
}
```

***Note:*** you're not checking if the given score exceeds the maximum range, in such case the last *enum-constant* would be returned. But since its name `D900_D1000` signifies that it represents a limited range values, you might want to add this check.